# behavior when there are two HTTP GET parameters with the same name

Tags: php, http

Say your HTTP request is formatted like this:

```
GET /path/to/file.php?var[]=1&var[]=2
```

PHP will populate that into an array named `$_GET`: `array('var' => array(1, 2))`

My question is...  is this a PHP thing or is this behavior governed by an RFC? How would a web accessible node.js or Python script deal with this?

Comment: It's language-specific.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's a PHP thing, on the basis that `?foo.bar=baz` gets converted to `$_GET['foo_bar'] = 'baz';`. Other server-side languages may provide similar features though.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol - that's interesting. I didn't know that!

Comment: @neubert Heh, yeah, I found it out the hard way when working with `<input type="image" />` coordinates ;) They get sent as `name.x` and `name.y` but PHP exposes them as `name_x` and `name_y`. I'm guessing this is a leftover from when "register globals" was a default thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP by default will overwrite previous values, and you end up with the LAST key:value pair found in the query string. But in PHP you can use the `[]` array as fieldname hack:

1. `example.com?foo=bar&foo=baz&foo=qux`
2. `example.com?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz&foo[]=qux`

Line #1 produces $_GET like this:

```
$_GET = array(
    'foo' => 'qux'
);
```

Line #2 produces

```
$_GET['array'] = array
   'foo' => array('bar', 'baz', 'qux');
}
```

Note that this behavior is PHP specific. Other languages do their own thing. As far as I remember, Perl by default will keep all values as an array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific feature of PHP with no related RFCs or other specs. I can't find any specific statements to that effect, but reading this FAQ Q/A seems to imply the same:

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays